# Spring Integration Multiplexing correlation

Tags: spring-integration

I am new to SI. I am using the code from the SI TCP Multiplexing example as a starting point for an app server I am writing. The caller of the service already exists and will be sending the payload prefixed by a byte length header. I am having a bit of trouble with the correlation of the response. As you can see below, I changed the Multiplexing example to first add a correlation id header to the incoming request before pushing on to the publish-subscribe-channel. The rest of the code is pretty much the same as the example.

So, the problem. The correlation id header is not available on the call to MessageController from the TcpSendingMessageHandler which serializes the message payload and sends it. Should I enrich the payload to include the correlation id (no correlation header) or is there a simpler way of doing all of this?  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
<gateway id="gw"
      service-interface="is.point.tokens.server.MessageGateway"
      default-request-channel="input">
</gateway>

<ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
            type="client"
            host="${tcpClientServer.address}"
            port="${tcpClientServer.port}"
            single-use="false"
            serializer="bigEndianFormatSerializer"
            deserializer="bigEndianFormatSerializer"
            so-timeout="10000"/>

<channel id="input" datatype="java.lang.String"/>

<header-enricher input-channel="input" output-channel="enriched.input">
     <correlation-id expression="headers['id']"/>
</header-enricher>

<publish-subscribe-channel id="enriched.input"/>

<ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="outAdapter.client"
                                     order="2"
                                     channel="enriched.input"
                                     connection-factory="client"/>
<!-- Collaborator -->

<!-- Also send a copy to the custom aggregator for correlation and
     so this message's replyChannel will be transferred to the
     aggregated message. The order ensures this gets to the aggregator first -->
    <bridge input-channel="enriched.input" output-channel="toAggregator.client" order="1"/>

    <!-- Asynchronously receive reply. -->
    <ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="inAdapter.client"
                                    channel="toAggregator.client"
                                    connection-factory="client"/>

<!-- Collaborator -->

<channel id="toAggregator.client" datatype="java.lang.String"/>

<aggregator input-channel="toAggregator.client"
                output-channel="toTransformer.client"
                correlation-strategy-expression="headers.get('correlationId')"
                release-strategy-expression="size() == 2">
</aggregator>

<!-- The response is always second -->
<transformer input-channel="toTransformer.client" expression="payload.get(1)"/>

    <!-- Server side -->

    <ip:tcp-connection-factory id="server"
                               type="server"
                               port="${tcpClientServer.port}"
                               using-nio="true"
                               serializer="bigEndianFormatSerializer"
                               deserializer="bigEndianFormatSerializer"/>

    <ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="inAdapter.server"
                                    channel="toSA"
                                    connection-factory="server" />

    <channel id="toSA" datatype="java.lang.String"/>

    <service-activator input-channel="toSA"
                       output-channel="toObAdapter"
                       ref="messageController"
                       method="handleMessage"/>

    <beans:bean id="messageController"
                class="example.server.MessageController"/>

    <channel id="toObAdapter"/>

    <ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="outAdapter.server"
                                     channel="toObAdapter"
                                     connection-factory="server"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need something in the data so the reply can be correlated.

But I am confused. If you are the server side for an existing application, then you can simply use an inbound gateway.

If you really are providing the client and server side, we did [add a mechanism in 3.0](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#ip-headers) to selectively add headers (to the tcp message), for example, using JSON.

**EDIT:**

From your comments, you only need the server side. All you need is this...

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="server"
    type="server"
    serializer="serializer"
    deserializer="serializer"
    port="${port}"/>

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="gateway"
    connection-factory="crLfServer"
    request-channel="toSA"
    error-channel="errorChannel"/>

<int:channel id="toSA" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="toSA"
    ref="messageController"
    method="handleMessage"/>

<bean id="serializer" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer" />
```

The fact that the service-activator has no output-channel means the framework will send the reply to the gateway automatically.

This assumes the service can handle a `byte[]`; if you need a String, you'll need a transformer like in the sample. Either way, the payload will not include the length header; it is stripped off (inbound) and added (outbound).

This also assumes the length header is 4 bytes (default); the serializer takes a size in a constructor...

```
<bean id="serializer" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer">
    <constructor-arg value="2" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment Gary. Maybe its not you that is confused :). So, I have a server that is handling some tokenization services for a few thousand distributed point of sale devices (pos). The pos devices need to interface with the server via tcp, hence I wanted to give SI a spin. It should be a simple request - response to and from the server from the pos. So can I use a simple inbound gateway? And the response from the sevice-activator...I need the server right? What I  am doing should be almost identical to the Collaborating Channel Adapters example, I think.

Comment: Please let me know if I'm just making mud pies and that there is a preferred way of doing this (appreciated). I will mess around with the header mapper fn. Thanks for that.

Comment: If you are the just the server then all you need is an inbound gateway and the service activator - see the simple tcp-client-server sample (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/tcp-client-server). The multiplex sample demostrates a more advanced technique for doing correlation on the `client` side when using async adapters instead of gateways.

Comment: I did play around with the basic examples first. When you say all I need is an inbound gateway (ex.tcpServerCustomSerialize-context) do you mean no client side config? No out-bound? I see the other examples here use an inbound and outbound gateway. I got this working in my project first but I started looking at the multiplex example bc of warnings in the doc about performance

Comment: I may have a pretty moderate volume on the server. I tried using the json mapper you mentioned. Its ok but I have 1 issue. The message coming from the pos clients use a byte prefix (big endian). The deserializer reads the payload from the stream then wraps everything in json. Which no longer has the byte prefix and therefore fails in subsequent serialization.

Comment: You don't need the client side at all; the samples have both in order to demonstrate both. The existing `ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer` handles a length header (network byte order - bigendian) with the header being 1, 2, or 4(default) bytes. The gateway performance considerations are on the client side; it's not an issue on the server side. I will edit my answer with all the bits you need.